# C++ advance user interface building

Tags: visual-c++, user-interface

I'm working on a new application to perform certain steps on certain order defined by the user.

My issue now is that I want to build a SSIS-like interface on Visual C++, something like this:

[image: SSIS designer UI]

The main idea is let the users to drag and drop elements on a blank section, and allow them also to rearrange them and create relations between them with arrows or lines.
Obviously SSIS designer UI allows to do much more than that, but at least something basic will help me to start.

I don't know how to make my search (I haven't found anything yet) or if anyone knows some tools or tutorials of this, I will really appreciate it.

**PS.** I'm open to any suggestions, even if they are in other programming languages. This application is intended to be for Windows.

Comment: Honestly it sounds like a bad idea to start doing a program like this using C++. Especially if it may be Windows only.

Comment: What would you suggest me? something like C#? if so, is there any library or framework on that language to do this?

Comment: C# seems like something normal people would use for things like this. I don't know too much about it, but you should not need any library/framework besides what's already included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code Project has a [Flow Chart Editor](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/flowcharteditor.aspx) class that appears to reasonably close to what you're looking for, at least in terms of visuals and editing (though it may easily be more elaborate than you really need).

Each item (box, line, etc.) in the diagram is represented by an object, so it should be relatively easy to attach actions to "execute" the graph in sequence. The obvious change you'll need to make is changing what are now free-form edit controls to become something like drop-down lists, so the user can only set the label for a particular box to be one of the actions you've made available to them (and, obviously, based on that selection you'll execute the actions they've chosen).

Comment: Perfect, just what I was looking for to start my concept. Thanks a lot.